# save data every 3 second and send an array every 5 minutes

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I got an MPU connected to a wemos d1 mini. The sensor send 3 values: X,Y and Z axis. Since my project is solar powered I need to reduce power consumption. In order to do so I want to read the 3 values of the MPU every 3 seconds, store the values in an array and after 5 minutes of sampling power up the wifi and send the array via mqtt to my topic.

I've already tested every part of my code and everything works.
For example if I try to send an array of three objects it works perfectly
But when I try to send an array of 100 objects it doesn't work.

(Note: Where the above "100" come from? If I need to send data every 5 minutes and I read values every 3 seconds here I have 100 samplings)

Hope someone could help

```cpp
unsigned long t_start;

void setup()
{
    t_start = millis();
}
//compute the required size
const size_t CAPACITY = JSON_ARRAY_SIZE(100) + 100 * JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(3);
//allocate the memory for the document
StaticJsonDocument<CAPACITY> doc;

//MPU
const int MPU = 0x68; // I2C address of the MPU-6050
int16_t AcX, AcY, AcZ;

void loop()
{
    //Create an empty array
    JsonArray arr = doc.to<JsonArray>();

    if (millis() - t_start >= 3000) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            //MPU reading
            Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
            Wire.write(0x3B); // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
            Wire.endTransmission(false);
            Wire.requestFrom(MPU, 14, true); // request a total of 14 registers
            AcX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)
            AcY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
            AcZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)

            //Create a JSON Object
            JsonObject obj = doc.createNestedObject();
            obj["AcX"] = AcX;
            obj["AcY"] = AcY;
            obj["AcZ"] = AcZ;
        }

        t_start = millis();
    }
}

//MQTT PUBLISHING JSON PACKAGE
char mqttData[MQTT_BUFFER];
serializeJson(doc, mqttData);
Serial.println(mqttData);
int ret = client.publish("esp8266/JSON", mqttData);
} //end of loop
```

Comment: what are you actually asking? how is your codes behaviour different from what you expect? please read [ask]

Comment: @Piglet edited. I don't know how to explain it better. What can't you understand? Maybe I can change

Comment: Maybe your MQTT Keep-Alive interval is less than 5 minutes, e.g. 60s.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not very informative. what about any own debugging attempts? if it does not work for 100 and works for 3, what's the number it starts to fail? does it fail with MQTT or also if you just print it to serial? this is not a debuggin service so we encourage people to narrow their problems down.

Comment: So you want to do one measure every 3 seconds? Why there is a loop that does it 100 times as fast as possible? Also is the code for publishing inside of loop? I can see 3 opening { and four closing }

Comment: @KIIV yes. I though that first I had to do all the sampling and then publish to my topic, that's why I used the for loop: one value every 3 second for a total of 100. How should i change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one measure every three seconds instead of 100 measures every 3 seconds, the code should look like this:

```cpp
#define MQTT_KEEPALIVE 300
// headers ...
// setup() ...

void loop() {
  //Create an empty array
  JsonArray arr = doc.to<JsonArray>();

  static auto t_start = millis(); // static will preserve last value even after exiting loop

  int8_t count = 0;
  while (count < 100) { // stays here whole 300s, so if the keep alives are needed or doing something else, it should be inside too
    client.loop(); // sugested in comments

    if (millis() - t_start >= 3000) {
      t_start += 3000;
      ++count;

      //MPU reading
      Wire.beginTransmission(MPU);
      Wire.write(0x3B); // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
      Wire.endTransmission(false);
      Wire.requestFrom(MPU, 14, true); // request a total of 14 registers
      AcX = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)
      AcY = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
      AcZ = Wire.read() << 8 | Wire.read(); // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)

      //Create a JSON Object
      JsonObject obj = doc.createNestedObject();
      obj["AcX"] = AcX;
      obj["AcY"] = AcY;
      obj["AcZ"] = AcZ;
    }

    // handling keep alives every X seconds as it's unlikely as long as 300s:
    // if (...) sendKeepAlive();
  }
  
  // after 100 measures it'll get here:

  //MQTT PUBLISHING JSON PACKAGE
  char mqttData[MQTT_BUFFER];
  serializeJson(doc, mqttData);
  Serial.println(mqttData);
  int ret = client.publish("esp8266/JSON", mqttData);
} //end of loop
```

However it should solve just most obvious issue with the code only. There might be others, like buffers might be too small, or so...

And it's untested, I don't have this HW setup

Comment: now on the serial monitor I get this error "rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)"

Comment: maybe something like wdt timeout or it have to leave loop more often (wdt, wifi handling)

Comment: Yes, definitely wdt. I'm not sure how to handle clearing json document without leaks, so it might be reasonable to store all measures into array(s) and create that json at the end

Comment: Add `mqttClient.loop();` to the beginning of your `loop()`. Also if you are only publishing an MQTT message every 5 minutes, add `define MQTT_KEEPALIVE 300` (default is 15 seconds) at the beginning of your code to keep the server connection from time out.